# How do I change a null string to non-null int in Entity Framework 2 Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is short: I have mistakenly set a property `string` when it should've been `int`. There are no constraints as this `int` may be optional. Even though I could make the int nullable, I rather have it a default value of zero.

Then when I try to run migrations:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Edad', table
>   'EduPlaTools.dbo.Profesor'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Which makes sense. What it's doing is updating the fields, and since many fields had "NULL", it's getting inserted. Is there a way to map those NULLs into zeroes automatically? Or do I need to do an SQL Statement?

Here's the migrationBuilder code:

```
   migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "Edad",
                table: "Profesor",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldNullable: true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `defaultValue: 0,`?

Comment: @RufusL: I tried that but I keep getting the same error

Comment: @RufusL: Please, see my answer. That did end up working once I selected the right table!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the type of a column and there are already existing records in your table, those records need to have some value specified for each of the new columns. If you have not specified a default value for the column, the database will attempt to use NULL, which will fail because the column does not allow nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Oh no. I need to apologize. So dumb for not realizing this, Entity Framework apparently scaffolded other table with a similar property `Profesor`, when in fact it was `Estudiante` that needed change.

```
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Edad",
            table: "Estudiante",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string),
            oldNullable: true,
            defaultValue: 0);
```

Now everything is working! Thanks everybody!